# Jetpack Compose Scoped/Smart Recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm doing experiments to comprehend recomposition and smart recomposition and made a sample

[image]

Sorry for the colors, they are generated with Random.nextIn() to observe recomposition visually, setting colors has no effect on recomposition, tried without changing colors either.

What's in gif is composed of three parts

**Sample1**

```
@Composable
private fun Sample1() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(getRandomColor())
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }


        Text("Sample1", color = getRandomColor())

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
            onClick = {
                counter++
            }) {
            Text("Counter: $counter", color = getRandomColor())
        }
    }
}
```

I have no questions here since smart composition works as expected, `Text` on top is not reading changes in `counter` so recomposition only occurs for `Text` inside `Button`.

**Sample2**

```
@Composable
private fun Sample2() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
    ) {

        var update1 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        var update2 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        println("ROOT")
        Text("Sample2", color = getRandomColor())

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 4.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
            onClick = {
                update1++
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        ) {

            println(" Button1️")

            Text(
                text = "Update1: $update1",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )

        }

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 2.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
            onClick = { update2++ },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        ) {
            println(" Button 2️")

            Text(
                text = "Update2: $update2",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
        ) {

            println(" Inner Column")
            var update3 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 2.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
                onClick = { update3++ },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
            ) {

                println("✅ Button 3️")
                Text(
                    text = "Update2: $update2, Update3: $update3",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = getRandomColor()
                )

            }
        }

        Column() {
            println("☕️ Bottom Column")
            Text(
                text = "Sample2",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )
        }

    }
}
```

It also works as expected each mutableState is updating only the scope they have been observed in. Only `Text` that observes `update2` and `update3` is changed when either of these mutableStates are updated.

**Sample3**

```
@Composable
private fun Sample3() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
    ) {


        var update1 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        var update2 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }


        println("ROOT")
        Text("Sample3", color = getRandomColor())

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 4.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
            onClick = {
                update1++
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        ) {

            println(" Button1️")

            Text(
                text = "Update1: $update1",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )

        }

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 2.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
            onClick = { update2++ },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        ) {
            println(" Button 2️")

            Text(
                text = "Update2: $update2",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )
        }

        Column {

            println(" Inner Column")
            var update3 by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 2.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = getRandomColor()),
                onClick = { update3++ },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
            ) {

                println("✅ Button 3️")
                Text(
                    text = "Update2: $update2, Update3: $update3",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = getRandomColor()
                )

            }
        }
       //  Reading update1 causes entire composable to recompose
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
        ) {
            println("☕️ Bottom Column")
            Text(
                text = "Update1: $update1",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Only difference between **Sample2** and **Sample3** is `Text` at the bottom is reading update1 mutableState which causing entire composable to be recomposed. As you can see in gif changing `update1` recomposes or changes entire color schema for Sample3.

What's the reason for recomposing entire composable?

```
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
        ) {
            println("☕️ Bottom Column")
            Text(
                text = "Update1: $update1",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = getRandomColor()
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I ask how do you test that recomposition happens in a piece of code? Is there any tool or just with log?

Comment: In article in the answer i posted there is a log code with `SideEffect`  that you can count number of recompositions. You can check with assertEquals the number in a test to expected.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To have smart recomposition scopes play a pivotal role. You can check Vinay Gaba's [What is “donut-hole skipping” in Jetpack Compose?](https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose) article.

Leland Richardson explains in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/intelligibabble/status/1435676765725224964?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1435676765725224964%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetpackcompose.app%2Farticles%2Fdonut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose) as

> The part that is "donut hole skipping" is the fact that a new lambda
> being passed into a composable (ie Button) can recompose without
> recompiling the rest of it. The fact that the lambda are recompose
> scopes are necessary for you to be able to do this,  but not
> sufficient
>
> In other words, composable lambda are "special" :)
>
> We wanted to do this for a long time but thought it was too
> complicated until @chuckjaz had the brilliant realization that if the
> lambdas were state objects, and invokes were reads, then this is
> exactly the result

You can also check other answers about smart recomposition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696157/when-will-jetpack-compose-launch-recomposition-and-what-will-be-recomposition/72696431#72696431), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72674227/5457853).

https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78

When a State is read it triggers recomposition in nearest scope. And a scope is a function that is not marked with inline and returns Unit. Column, Row and Box are inline functions and because of that they don't create scopes.

Created `RandomColorColumn` that take other `Composables` and its scope `content: @Composable () -> Unit`

```
@Composable
fun RandomColorColumn(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .shadow(1.dp, shape = CutCornerShape(topEnd = 8.dp))
            .background(getRandomColor())
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

And replaced

```
 Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())
    ) {
        println("☕️ Bottom Column")
        Text(
            text = "Update1: $update1",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = getRandomColor()
        )
    }
}
```

with

```
    RandomColorColumn() {

        println("☕️ Bottom Column")
        /*
             Observing update(mutableState) does NOT causes entire composable to recompose
         */
        Text(
            text = " Update1: $update1",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = getRandomColor()
        )
    }
}
```

Only this scope gets updated as expected and we have smart recomposition.

[image]

What causes `Text`, or any Composable, inside `Column` to not have a scope, thus being recomposed when a mutableState value changes is `Column` having **inline** keyword in function signature.

```
@Composable
inline fun Column(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val measurePolicy = columnMeasurePolicy(verticalArrangement, horizontalAlignment)
    Layout(
        content = { ColumnScopeInstance.content() },
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

If you add **inline** to `RandomColorColumn` function signature you will see that it causes **whole Composable to recompose**.

Compose uses [call sites](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#composition-anatomy) defined as

> The call site is the source code location in which a composable is
> called. This influences its place in Composition, and therefore, the
> UI tree.
>
> If during a recomposition a composable calls different composables
> than it did during the previous composition, Compose will identify
> which composables were called or not called and for the composables
> that were called in both compositions, Compose will avoid recomposing
> them if their inputs haven't changed.

Consider the following example:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(showError: Boolean) {
    if (showError) {
        LoginError()
    }
    LoginInput() // This call site affects where LoginInput is placed in Composition
}

@Composable
fun LoginInput() { /* ... */ }
```

Call site of a Composable function affects smart recomposition, and having **inline** keyword in a Composable sets its child Composables call site same level, not one level below.

For anyone interested here is the [github repo](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#4-2-3-scoped-recomposition) to play/test recomposition

Comment: The info about the inline keyword and the article were really helpful, thanks for mentioning it!