# Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mutablestateof

I've been playing with Jetpack Compose Desktop. I noticed something I really don't understand:

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by mutableStateOf("Hello, World!")

    MaterialTheme {
        TextField(text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

Why am I able to change the text in the `TextField`? I thought that on every recompose the mutable state get reinstantiated with the initial value: so the `Text` should not be able to change

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by mutableStateOf("Hello, World!")

    Column {
        TextField(text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

However, if you replace the `MaterialTheme` with a `Column` it suddenly works as expected and you aren't able to change the text in the `TextField`.

Why is that? Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a feature of Compose about scoping and smart recomposition. You can check my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition/71016788#71016788).

What really makes your whole `Composable` recompose is that `Column` is defined using the **`inline`** keyword.

```
@Composable
inline fun Column(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val measurePolicy = columnMeasurePolicy(verticalArrangement, horizontalAlignment)
    Layout(
        content = { ColumnScopeInstance.content() },
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

Let's say you have a `Composable` that sets the background color initially at composition and changes it at each recomposition which creates its own scope. A lambda without `inline` is considered a scope.

```
@Composable
fun RandomColorColumn(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .shadow(1.dp, shape = CutCornerShape(topEnd = 8.dp))
            .background(getRandomColor())
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

With

```
@Composable
fun App2() {
    var text by mutableStateOf("Hello, World!")

    RandomColorColumn {
        TextField(text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

And one with `Column`

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    var text by mutableStateOf("Hello, World!")

    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor())) {
        TextField(text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Random color function

```
fun getRandomColor() =  Color(
    red = Random.nextInt(256),
    green = Random.nextInt(256),
    blue = Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)
```

You will see that Column background color will change every time you change text but not with `App2()`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> I thought, that on every recompose the mutable state get reinstanciated with the initial Value: so the Text should not be able to change

The point of having a state when recomposing is to prevent a variable from being re-initialized. The initial state is used only once when the first composition occurs and isn't used again when further recompositions occur. If however the composable is removed from the UI tree and then reinstated later on, the state of the variable will be destroyed and re-initialized as this is not really a recomposition but a composition (as if it were happening for the first time).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but why does it work then