# Unexpected re-composition when using Java classes (even if not being read/observed)

Tags: java, android, static, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm using `java.time` for some part of my app's functionality and I'm getting `re-compositions` unexpectedly. Consider the codes below with some `Java` classes.

RootJavaClass

```
public class RootJavaClass {
     public static AnotherJavaClass getNewInstance() {
         return new AnotherJavaClass("Hello There");
     }
}
```

AnotherJavaClass

```
public class AnotherJavaClass {
     public String data = "";
     public AnotherJavaClass(String param) {
         data = param;
     }
 }
```

My Parent Scope Composable

```
@Composable
internal fun ParentComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var stateLessObject = RootJavaClass.getNewInstance()
    var mutableStateObject by remember { mutableStateOf(stateLessObject)}

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
            mutableStateObject = it
        }

        ReadsAMutableState(mutableStateObject)
    }
}
```

and a child composable inside the parent composable

```
@Composable // this composable is being re-composed unwantedly
fun DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(
    stateLessObject : AnotherJavaClass,
    onButtonClick : (AnotherJavaClass) -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            onButtonClick(AnotherJavaClass("GoodBye"))
        },
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stateLessObject.data
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ReadsAMutableState(
    mutableStateObject: AnotherJavaClass
) {
    Text(
        text = mutableStateObject.data
    )
}
```

Why does the `DoesNotReadAnyMutableState` composable is being `re-composed`? even if it doesn't read the `mutableState` object?, this does not happen with ordinary classes even with a simple `String`.

This only happens when I use `static referenced object`, set it to be `remembered` as the initial value of the `mutable state object` and modify that object ( as you can see in the `lambda` callback )

Edit:

I made some changes referencing the answer from another post regarding Smart Re-composition, credits to @Thracian
[Smart Re-composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition)

I created my own non-inlined `Column{..}` scope

```
@Composable
fun MyOwnColumnScope(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

and used it this way

```
MyOwnColumnScope {
    DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
        mutableValue = it
    }

    ReadsAMutableState(mutableValue)
}
```

but it still triggers the un-wanted recomposition.

I'm not quite sure if there's a special case within the usage of `static`s, or if this is a bug within the `snapshot` \ `compose` framework?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Column` doesn't create a recomposition scope. And on each recomposition you create new instance of `stateLessObject` and pass it to `DoesNotReadAnyMutableState` Composable.

When a State is read it triggers recomposition in nearest scope. And a scope is a function that is not marked with inline and returns Unit. Column, Row and Box are inline functions and because of that they don't create scopes.

If you change your Column into the Composable above it won't be recomposed.

```
@Composable
private fun MyColumn(modifier: Modifier,content: @Composable ()->Unit) {
    Column(modifier=modifier){
        content()
    }
}
```

I did further testing. First, when it's Kotlin class it definitely requires non-inlined function to have scoped function to not recompose `DoesNotReadAnyMutableState`

```
@Composable // this composable is being re-composed unwantedly
fun DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(
    stateLessObject: AnotherJavaClass,
    onButtonClick: (AnotherJavaClass) -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            onButtonClick(AnotherJavaClass("GoodBye"))
        },
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stateLessObject.data
        )
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(getRandomColor())
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(20.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun ReadsAMutableState(
    mutableStateObject: AnotherJavaClass
) {
    Text(
        text = mutableStateObject.data
    )
}


@Composable
internal fun ParentComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var stateLessObject = MyData("Column")
    var mutableStateObject by remember { mutableStateOf(stateLessObject) }

    Column(
    ) {
        DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
            mutableStateObject = it
        }

        ReadsAMutableState(mutableStateObject)
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun ParentComposable2(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var stateLessObject = MyData("MyColumn")
    var mutableStateObject by remember { mutableStateOf(stateLessObject) }

    MyColumn() {
        DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
            mutableStateObject = it
        }

        ReadsAMutableState(mutableStateObject)
    }
}

class MyData(val data: String)
```

Result

[image]

Then changed MyData class to one below and created another one that returns same instance

```
class MyData() {
    val anotherJavaClass: AnotherJavaClass
        get() = AnotherJavaClass("")
}

class MyData2() {
    val anotherJavaClass = AnotherJavaClass("")
}
```

And parent classes to

```
@Composable
internal fun ParentComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var stateLessObject = MyData().anotherJavaClass

    LogCompositions(" ParentComposable() ${stateLessObject.hashCode()}")

    var mutableStateObject by remember { mutableStateOf(stateLessObject) }

    MyColumn() {

        LogCompositions(" ParentComposable() MyColumn scope ${stateLessObject.hashCode()}")

        DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
            mutableStateObject = it
        }

        ReadsAMutableState(mutableStateObject)
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun ParentComposable2(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var stateLessObject = MyData2().anotherJavaClass
    var mutableStateObject by remember { mutableStateOf(stateLessObject) }
    LogCompositions(" ParentComposable2() ${stateLessObject.hashCode()}")

    MyColumn() {
        LogCompositions(" ParentComposable2() scope ${stateLessObject.hashCode()}")

        DoesNotReadAnyMutableState(stateLessObject = stateLessObject) {
            mutableStateObject = it
        }

        ReadsAMutableState(mutableStateObject)
    }
}
```

LogComposition is

```
class Ref(var value: Int)

// Note the inline function below which ensures that this function is essentially
// copied at the call site to ensure that its logging only recompositions from the
// original call site.
@Composable
inline fun LogCompositions(msg: String) {
    val ref = remember { Ref(0) }
    SideEffect { ref.value++ }
    println("$msg, recomposition: ${ref.value}")
}
```

Result

[image]

When non-inlined function used it doesn't recompose parent but `java class` with or without static causing scope to trigger recomposition but i don't know why yet.

You can check my other answers about scoped/smart recomposition below

[Jetpack Compose Smart Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition)

[Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How can I launch recomposition when a specified Flow changed in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673880/how-can-i-launch-recomposition-when-a-specified-flow-changed-in-jetpack-compose?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[When will Jetpack Compose launch recomposition and what will be recomposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696157/when-will-jetpack-compose-launch-recomposition-and-what-will-be-recomposition?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There are very good articles in the link i suggest you to check out.

Comment: Thank you @Thracian, I tried to apply your scoped/smart re-composition, and it still triggers the un-wanted `re-composition` pass, also, like I mentioned, when I don't use `static references`(e.g String, Int objects etc) it performs a `smart recomposition` without having to implement a `non-inlined` `Column{...}` scope. Is there any special cases with `statics`? or is this a bug within the `snapshot` framework?

Comment: Based on a podcast I watched where Chuck Jazdzewski said (based on the context I understand), when the `snapshot` sees a state value changed, it will send a `notification`  to the `composer` and it will trigger a `re-composition` to those `composables` that observes that `state`, so does `compose` observes `statics` same way it observes `mutableState` objects?

Comment: I run some tests and added them as sample. Even without static accessing java class triggers recomposition inside scope. But using an non-inline function creates a scope thus it limits composition inside it if you check examples you will see that lines or logs above `MyColumn`is not recomposed or invoked

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea. I had never tried using java classes before.