# Android Jetpack Compose - Composable Function get recomposed each time Text-field value changes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm using `TextField` to get user input and using stateflow to handle the text state/value in viewmodel.

The thing is every time `TextField`'s value changes the `HomeContent()` function get recomposed.
[Layout inspector output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr7mi.png)
My question is, is it ok that the whole `HomeContent()` function is getting recomposed just because the `TextField` value changes or is there a way of avoiding function recomposition?

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _nameFlow = MutableStateFlow("")
    val nameFlow = _nameFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun updateName(name: String) {
        _nameFlow.value = name
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val myViewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppArchitectureTheme {
                HelloScreen(myViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeScreen

```
@Composable
fun HelloScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val name = viewModel.nameFlow.collectAsState()
    HelloContent(
        provideName = { name.value },
        onNameChange = { viewModel.updateName(it) })
}

@Composable
fun HelloContent(
    provideName: () -> String,
    onNameChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello,",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = provideName(),
            onValueChange = { onNameChange(it) },
            label = { Text("Name") }
        )
        Button(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(text = "Dummy Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that `HomeContent` is being recomposed, but you have one composable called `HomeScreen` and one called `HelloContent`. Neither one is called `HomeContent`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behavior. Compose recomposes only the "nearest" scope. A scope is non-inline Composable function that returns `Unit`.

You can read answers about this in the links below. However, the difference between the question and answers in the link(s) is you also [defer reading change](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#defer-reads) which keeps Composables in between from being recomposed when the value inside the lambda changes.

[Jetpack Compose Smart Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition)

[Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How can I launch recomposition when a specified Flow changed in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673880/how-can-i-launch-recomposition-when-a-specified-flow-changed-in-jetpack-compose?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If you change `OutlinedTextField` to

```
@Composable
private fun MyOutlinedTextField(
    provideName: () -> String,
    onNameChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = provideName(),
        onValueChange = { onNameChange(it) },
        label = { Text("Name") }
    )
}
```

this function will only be recomposed when the parameter it reads changes. If there were multiple `MyOutlinedTextField`, only the one that reads the respective value would change.

However, a subtle and very important difference between this and the answers in links that I provided, is deferring state-read by passing

`provideName: () -> String` instead of `provideName: String`

This defers state-reads from descendent Composables to only the one that reads this lambda. That's how you trigger recompositions only for `MyOutlinedTextField` scope.

If you update your function as below, you will see that it will again recompose the whole `HelloContent` scope including the `Text` inside the `Column` here,

```
@Composable
fun HelloContent(
    provideName: String,
    onNameChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(getRandomColor())
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Column( Modifier
            .background(getRandomColor())) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello,",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
            )
        }

        MyOutlinedTextField(provideName = provideName, onNameChange = onNameChange)

        Button(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Dummy Button", modifier = Modifier
                    .background(getRandomColor())
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This function recomposes the `Column` where the random color function is

```
fun getRandomColor(): Color {
    return Color(
        Random.nextInt(256),
        Random.nextInt(256),
        Random.nextInt(256),
        255
    )
}
```

Also, this is the tutorial I prepared which covers scoped recomposition and deferring reads. You can check out this example for reading offset, and padding changes.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter4_state/Tutorial4_7_3ComposePhases3.kt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't extract a `val` outside the `HelloContent`'s calling site. Move the initialization logic to the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Thracian is correct, but I want to clarify this section:

> Compose recomposes only the "nearest" scope. A scope is non-inline Composable function that returns Unit.

In your example, `Column` is an inline function, therefore the nearest scope non-inline Composable function is `HelloContent` and this is the reason why it gets recomposed.