# mutableStateOf holding the value after the recomposition without remember API in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition, mutablestateof

> Any time a state is updated a recomposition takes place.

but here, I haven't used the remember API, but after the recomposition also it's holding the value, is the `mutableStateOf()` will remember the value without `remember` API?

```
@Composable
fun MyChildUI() {

    var count by mutableStateOf(1)

    Button(onClick = {
        count++
        println(count)
    }) {
        Text(text = "$count")
    }
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of scoped recomposition. Any Composable that is not inline and returns Unit is a scope. Compose only triggers recomposition in nearest scope. In your example it's Button's scope. You can check out this question which is very similar

[Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular example when you click the button, only lines 42-47 will be recomposed. You can verify this by adding a log statement in line 41.

When the whole `MyChildUI` composable recomposes, the value of the `count` will be reset to 1.

So, you should use `remember` to avoid issues.