# remember derivedStateOf or not

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

In the examples I find ([here](https://developermemos.com/posts/derived-state-jetpack-compose) or [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof)) I see that `derivedStateOf` is always wrapped in a `remember` block. Checking the Recomposition counts, I don't see a difference between

```
val foo = remember { derivedStateOf { someState } }
```

and

```
val foo = derivedStateOf { someState }
```

Could anyone show me an example where the result would differ?

Edit:
So I got a different result in this example:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var count by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val moreThanOne = derivedStateOf {
        Log.d("foo", "Calculate")
        count > 1
    }

    Log.d("foo", "Read")
    moreThanOne.value

    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.d("foo", "Clicked")
            count += 1
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increment")
    }
}
```

Clicking the Button twice gives the following log:

```
Read
Calculate
Clicked
Calculate
Clicked
Calculate
Read
Calculate
```

Wrapping the `derivedStateOf` with a `remember` however logs:

```
Read
Calculate
Clicked
Calculate
Clicked
Calculate
Read
```

Still not completely sure why I see what I see.

Comment: Probably the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/71045838/115145 and https://pocraft.medium.com/why-bother-remember-state-in-jetpack-compose-c9ded9bc15ec

Comment: Did the second one not wrapped inside a `remember{ ... }` compile?

Comment: I added some new findings

Comment: Jetpack Compose 1.3.0+ gives a warning if you don't remember a `derivedStateOf`, so you actually do need to use `remember {}` around a `derivedStateOf`. In fact, you should "remember" any parameters that are used within `derivedStateOf { a + b }` then it should be `= remember(a, b) { derivedStateOf { a + b }}`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, you can get past it by annotating your composable function with `@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")`

Comment: @z.y I **don't** want to **not** remember the mutable state, that would mean i'm getting no benefits from evaluation at all

Comment: Well the difference is that if you don't use `remember {}` then it will be as if you didn't even try to use derived state. You'd just create a new one on each recomposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should look like,

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var count by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val moreThanOne = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            Log.d("foo", "Calculate")
            count > 1
        }
    }

    Log.d("foo", "Read")
    moreThanOne.value

    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.d("foo", "Clicked")
            count += 1
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Increment")
    }
}
```

Note the additional `remember` around `derivedStateOf`. This doesn't affect the results of the logging but the lack of `remember` around the `derivedStateOf` requires additional overhead cause by the creating of a new `derivedStateOf` every time `Test` runs. You should always remember `derivedStateOf` when in a composable function.

From this code I receive the following:

```
D/foo: Read
D/foo: Calculate
D/foo: Clicked
D/foo: Calculate
D/foo: Clicked
D/foo: Calculate
D/foo: Read
D/foo: Clicked
D/foo: Calculate
D/foo: Clicked
D/foo: Calculate
D/foo: Clicked
D/foo: Calculate
```

The first `Read` and `Calculated` are from initial composition. The value of `count` is `0`.

After the first click `Calculated` is emitted but nothing else. This is cause by `Test` becoming conditionally invalidated by the change of `count`. It is conditional in that `Test` is only called if the calculated value of `moreThanOne` is different than previous read by `Test`. In this case it returns `false` again so `Test` is not called.

The second click `Calculate` is seen again and now `moreThanOne` produces `true` which causes the conditional invalidation of `Test` to be treated as a real invalidation and `Test` is invoked to update the composition.

The third and subsequent clicks just produce `Calculated` as the lambda is invoked (because `count` changed) but the result of `moreThanOne` is not different so the conditional invalidation of `Test` is ignored.

The reason `Calculated` appears before `Read` even though the log of `Read` is before the expression `moreThanOne.value` is that the current value of `moreThanOne` is updated prior to `Test` being called to see if `Test` needs to be called at all. If, however, `Test` was invalidated for some other reason (that is, it read some other state object that changed) then `moreThanOne` would only be updated by the call to `moreThanOne.value`. Derived state objects are only updated prior to the call to `Test` if they are the only reason `Test` is being requested to be re-invoked. If they return the same value as the prior composition then the invalidation is ignored and the call is skipped.