# Why simple Text() recomposed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a dialog with header, message, input string and 2 buttons based on AlertDialog.
Full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Foenix00001/9bccd736a7f447f52cde246a629c6ce6)

Before refactoring my buttons recomposed when user enters text, I change it, but did not touch the message. And after that suddenly message starts to recompose when user enters text.
The picture is like this now.
[image]

I did investigate this, but with no luck. If I change the message with simple constant like "message" the recompositing is not happen. If I change the message with constant stringResourse(...) inside dialog (not in screen function) the recompositing is not happen. May be this is a bug in compose?

Comment: Jetpack Compose looks for nearest scope for recomposition. A scope is a Composable function that is non-inline returns unit. Wrapping your function with a non-inline function creates this scope. You can refer these answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: how would you explain my last note about changing message to constant or stringResourse?

Comment: @Foenix How do you check that it is not recomposed?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti,  it is white in Layout Inspector , also it says 0.

Comment: @Foenix check with the colors, not with the layout inspector.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because when the `text` state is updated all the composables in the nearest scope are recomposed.
The same happens also with a static text.

The message and the text are in the same scope (also the text counter)

```
Text(text = message)
TextField( 
     value = text,
     onValueChange = {
          text = it
     }
)
```

You can check visually using:

```
fun getRandomColor() =  Color(
    red = Random.nextInt(256),
    green = Random.nextInt(256),
    blue = Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)
```

and:

```
Text(text = "message", color = getRandomColor())
TextField(
      value = text,
      onValueChange = {
          text = it
      },
      colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(focusedTextColor = getRandomColor())
)
```

[image]

If you want to avoid it you can wrap your `TextField` with a Composable like

```
@Composable
fun MyColumn(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Column(
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

using:

```
Text(text = message)
MyColumn(){
   TextField( 
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
       }
   )
}
```

Check these great answers by Thracian for more details:

- [Jetpack Compose Smart Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-smart-recomposition)
- [Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: how would you explain my last note about changing message to constant or stringResourse? I wrote this in the last sentences