# Jetpack Compose: Surface makes state is persisting without remember

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, mutablestateof

im currently experiencing with jetpack compose states.

Check out this composable:

```
@Composable
fun CounterWithoutRemember(reset: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val count = mutableStateOf(0)

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Column {
            Text("Your count: ${count.value}")
            ElevatedButton(onClick = {
                count.value += 1
            }) {
                Text("Add 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working as expected. count is state without remember, that makes it resetting to 0 after recomposition.

But this code :

```
@Composable
fun CounterWithoutRemember(reset: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val count = mutableStateOf(0)

    Surface(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Column {
            Text("Your count: ${count.value}")
            ElevatedButton(onClick = {
                count.value += 1
            }) {
                Text("Add 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I change the Box with Surface. with this code, i see that the count state is persisting like when i use remember when that composable recomposes. Can anyone explain me?

this is the activity :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val resetState = mutableStateOf(false)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(Modifier.padding(52.dp)) {
                    Column {
                        Counter()
                        CounterWithRemember(resetState)
                        CounterWithoutRemember(resetState)
                        ElevatedButton(onClick = {

                            resetState.value = !resetState.value

                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Reset")
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Column`, `Row`, and `Box` are `inline` functions and they don't create scopes, however `Surface` creates a scope as any other Composable that is **not** `inline` and returns `Unit` that limits composition range. Because of that `CounterWithoutRemember` is not recomposed.

```
@Composable
fun CounterWithoutRemember(reset: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val count = mutableStateOf(0)

    Surface(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Column {
            Text("Your count: ${count.value}")
            ElevatedButton(onClick = {
                count.value += 1
            }) {
                Text("Add 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Why does mutableStateOf without remember work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045838/why-does-mutablestateof-without-remember-work-sometimes?noredirect=1&lq=1)