# Jetpack compose when to create a new lambda instance in Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Please see my code:

```
@Composable
fun RecomposeLambdaTest() {
    var state by remember {
        mutableStateOf("1")
    }

    val stateHolder = remember {
        StateHolder()
    }
    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            state += "1"
        }) {
            Text(text = "change the state")
        }
        OuterComposable(state = state) {
            stateHolder// just a reference to the instance outer the scope
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OuterComposable(state: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    LogUtil.d("lambda hashcode: ${onClick.hashCode()}")

    Column {
        Text(text = state)

        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Log.d("Jeck", "compose 2")
            Text(text = "Text")
        }
    }
}

//@Stable
class StateHolder{
    private var b  = 2
}
```

**Every time I click button, *OuterComposable* recompose, and log the lambda hashcode——always different! It means that a new lambda instance is created when recompose, everytime**

and I uncomment the code in StateHolder and make it look like:

```kotlin
@Stable
class StateHolder{
    private var b  = 2
}
```

**Every time I click button, *OuterComposable* recompose, and log the lambda hashcode——always the same! It means that when recompose, Composer reuse the lambda**

So what' s under the hood?

Edit:
Ok, make it easier, Let's change the code like this:

```kotlin
val stateHolder = remember {
        2
}
```

the result is lambda is reused.
make val to var, the lambda is created when every recompose.

So I think I know that: If the lambda refenence a valuable outer scope and the valuable is not stable, recreate lambda every time.

So the question is:

1. Why Compose compiler do this?
2. Why Compiler think the StateHolder before is not stable, it only contains a private var!?

Comment: you are printing the hash of the lambda

Comment: @zjmo could you explain it in detail, do you think the lambda is not a new instance?

Comment: ah yes I misunderstood. Probably is because compose cannot understand if stateHolder is referencing the same object. What happen if you wrap StateHolder instance in a mutableStateOf()?

Comment: I'm having a hint why this is happening, but still not able to grasp it fully, what your'e  trying to do here might be explained by this article of [Ben Trengrove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616971/ben-trengrove) that I got from a fellow S.O [@Stable/@Immutable](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An author met the same question, here is his article——[6 Jetpack Compose Guidelines to Optimize Your App Performance](https://getstream.io/blog/jetpack-compose-guidelines/#rules-for-writing-classes)

He said, private property still affact stability, it seems it is a Google team's choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
class StateHolder{
   private var b  = 2
}
```

In this class b variable is mutable and any mutable variable makes the class unstable. So when recompose compose this this value will be changed as this is var.

Check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability?authuser=1) for details