# Android Compose side effects: Side-Effect behavior

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I'm probably missing some important composable recomposition concepts here but let me explain my doubt.

I was reading about **side effects in Android Compose** and I findout that specifically **SideEffect** composable function gets executed only when the parent composable function is recomposed. Meaning, every time parent composable function is recomposed, any effect of a **SideEffect** will be executed. Now, recomposition happens when:

1. A composable function is reinvoked with different parameters.
2. Internal state in the composable function changes.

So if we have this simple counter composable function called **Counter1**, **SideEffect** inside of it will be executed when this function first launches and, after that, every time the user increases the count (every time the user clicks on the Button):

```
@Composable
fun Counter1() {
    var counter: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    SideEffect {
        Log.d("Test tag", "Counter1: $counter")
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
            Text(text = "Increase count")
        }
        Text(text = "Counter value is: $counter")
    }
}
```

If we change that counter a little bit and we produce this other one:

```
@Composable
fun Counter2() {
    var counter: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    SideEffect {
        Log.d("Test tag", "Counter2: $counter")
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
            Text(text = "Increase count is: $counter")
        }
    }
}
```

SideEffect in this second scneario will only be executed the first time the composable is recomposed. It will not be executed when the user changes the state (by increasing the counter). Why is this happening? I put a break point at the first line in **Counter2** and every time the user clicks on the button, the counter value is increased and the **Counter2** is reinvoked with a new state.

1. Why is **side effect** not being executed in **Counter2** after the state changes and **Counter2** is recomposed?
2. Is only **Text** function inside **Button** function being recomposed?
3. If 2. is true, why is not the entire **Counter2** being recomposed but **Counter1** is?

#### Thanks in advance team!

Comment: The issue is `Column` is an `inline` function that does not create a **scope**. Scope  determines  start and end range for recomposition. You can refer this question and answer for details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257459/jetpack-compose-scoped-smart-recomposition

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Thracian's comment, what `SideEffect` interprets as a recomposition is restricted to the part of the compose tree where `SideEffect` is located. Yes, there is a recomposition everytime the counter is increased, but not *everything* is recomposed, just the affected composables.

Although the `counter` state variable in **Counter2** is in the same compose scope as the side effect, it is not used anywhere in that scope so no recomposition is necessary (and the side effect is skipped). It is used in the `Button` composable to call `Text`, but that is a separate compose function that has its own scope.

The interesting part is why **Counter1** behaves differently. Now the `counter` is used only in the `Column` composable to call `Text`, but `Column` also is another composable function that should have its own scope and *should* therefore behave the same (which it doesn't).

Here is where @Thracian's comment comes into play: `Column` is not just a compose function, it is also declared as an [`inline` function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html). That means that the compiler inlines the function by replacing every call of the function with a copy of its body, then the function is removed. In the compiled code there is no call to another compose function, therefore no new compose scope is created and the content of `Column` uses the surrounding scope instead. And that happens to be the same where the `SideEffect` is located.

That is why changing `counter` in **Counter1** triggers a recomposition of the scope that contains the `SideEffect`, because it is the same that contains the `Text` (that accesses `counter`).