# mutableStateOf and Objects

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

Good day! I have a composable that takes a property from an object. The problem is whenever I change the property of the class through its property, the class property reflects the change in a different manner.

```
val customerFormData by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(CustomerFormData()) }
    LabelWithTextBox(
    label = "Customer Form Data:",
    textBoxValue = customerFormData.customerName,
    onChangeHandler = {
        customerFormData.customerName = it
        println(customerFormData.toString())
    }
    )
```

```
@Composable
fun LabelWithTextBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: String,
    textBoxValue: String,
    onChangeHandler: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Surface {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(label)
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            )

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp),
                border = BorderStroke(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    brush = SolidColor(Color.Black)
                )
            ) {
                BasicTextField(
                    value = textBoxValue,
                    onValueChange = onChangeHandler,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    decorationBox = {
                        Row(
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)
                        ) {
                            it()
                        }
                    },
                    singleLine = true
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
data class CustomerFormData(
    var customerID: String = "",
    var customerName: String = "",
    var address: String = "",
    var deliveryAddress: String = "",
    var tin: String = "",
    var email: String = "",
    var telephoneNumber: String = "",
    var cellphoneNumber: String = "",
    var contactPersonName: String = "",
    var contactPersonEmail: String = "",
    var contactPersonTelephoneNumber: String = "",
    var contactPersonCellphoneNUmber: String = "",
)
```

I expected that if I enter "asdasd" in my Composable the customerName field would be "asdasd". But instead I got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH0hH.png)

What seems to be the problem here? Thank you for your responses.

I have tried hoisting the state object to a higher level, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Please edit your post and also include the code of the `LabelWithTextBox` Composable and your `CustomerFormData` class. It appears that the onChangeHandler only returns the newly added character instead of the whole String in the text field.

Comment: @BenjyTec I apologize for the lack of code. Here are the codes for the CustomerFormData class and the LabelWithTextBox composable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose - Why remembered custom object not holding changes after recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72704492/jetpack-compose-why-remembered-custom-object-not-holding-changes-after-recompo)

Answer (score 1):

To add some explanation for the behavior you are observing:

- You start typing "asdasd" and type "a".
- The `TextField` triggers the `onValueChange` callback with "a".
- You are setting "a" to the state object and are printing that value. However, Jetpack Compose does not recognize this change and no recomposition happens. The `TextField` `value` is not updated and remains an empty String.
- You type "s".
- The `TextField` triggers the `onValueChange` callback. As the current `value` of the `TextField` still is an empty String, it returns only the new letter "s".
- You are setting "s" to the state object and are printing that value. However, Jetpack Compose again does not recognize this change and no recomposition happens.
- This happens for all letters.

To make Jetpack Compose recognize the changes to the `CustomerFormData` object,  you either need to assign an updated instance to the variable like this:

```
customerFormData = customerFormData.copy(customerName = it)
```

Or you can wrap all the fields of your `CustomerFormData` class into a `MutableState` so that Jetpack Compose can recognize the changes:

```
data class CustomerFormData(
    val customerID = mutableStateOf(""),
    var customerName = mutableStateOf(""),
    // ...
)
```

To avoid this common pitfall in the future, it is always recommended to define the fields of a data class as `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: what solution do you think is better in terms of performance?

Comment: See the following stackoverflow post for some thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180232/performance-implications-of-holding-state-in-large-data-classes-and-updating-it
In your case, as you are only passing the `customerFormData.customerName` to the `LabelWithTextBoxComposable` and not the whole `CustomerFormData` object, both approaches should be fine.